# What is Saika constantly posting on the Message Board?

Tags: japanese-language, durarara

[image: Saika on Durarara Message Board]

I'm on the first season of *Durarara!!* (Coalgirls Subs), and on the Message Board Saika often posts random words like *Love, Peace, Cut, etc.* - All of which are subbed except for this repeated character.

Initially I thought that Saika might be spamming with `DESU DESU` or something similar (I don't know why I thought that), but googling this didn't return any results.

So my question is, ***What is this word, Saika is constantly spamming the board with?***

Comment: [母](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8D#Japanese) means 'mother', does that make sense in the context?

Comment: Well no, like I said Saika just spams with random words on the board. Anyways, thanks for helping out. `Mother` seems to be the correct translation.

Comment: You will understand the meaning later.

Comment: Going back and re-watching the scenes a couple of times, [I came across this](http://jmp.sh/5bHE6jU). It's a 1-second scene with the 母 character subbed as 'Mother'. Missed it the first few times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[母{はは} (haha)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8D#Japanese) is the Kanji for 'mother'.

Comment: Can it be read as laughter then? Or does have a different meaning in this context? I've watched the entire series and I'm not sure it's not just randomness because some characters are like that, but it could also be a calling to the parent sword which infected this person. Could you clarify this in your answer?

Comment: @Hakase I'm afraid I can't you help there since I've never seen the anime. I was just commenting on what the Kanji means. I'm also not aware of the character being used for laughter but that doesn't seem too far fetched and I'm not an expert on 2ch culture ;) Apparently [Kalilz](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19294/what-is-saika-constantly-posting-on-the-message-board/19295?#comment24807_19294) knew more about it?